# Error when installing Gurobi package Julia

Tags: windows, julia, gurobi

I downloaded Gurobi and verified that my license is working.
I'm trying to add the Gurobi package to Julia, but it seems that the dll file can't be found, even though my GUROBI_HOME variable is okay.

Here is the output of Pkg.build("Gurobi") :

Found GUROBI_HOME =  C:\gurobi902\win64

Does this point to the correct install location?

- on Windows, this might be `C:\Program Files\gurobi810\win64\`
- alternatively, on Windows, this might be `C:/Program Files/gurobi810/win64/`
- on OSX, this might be `/Library/gurobi810/mac64/`
- on Unix, this might be `/home/my_user/gurobi810/linux64/`

Note: this has to be a full path, not a path relative to your current
directory or your home directory.

We're going to look for the Gurobi library in this directory:
C:\gurobi902\win64\bin

That directory has the following files:

- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\grbcluster.exe
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\grbgetkey.exe
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\grbprobe.exe
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\grbtune.exe
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\grb_ts.exe
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\gurobi.bat
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\gurobi.env
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\gurobi90.dll
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\Gurobi90.NET.dll
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\Gurobi90.NET.XML
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\gurobi90_light.dll
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\GurobiJni90.dll
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\gurobi_cl.exe
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\pysetup.bat
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\vslauncher.exe
- C:\gurobi902\win64\bin\vswhere.exe

We were looking for (but could not find) a file named like
`libgurobiXXX.so`, `libgurobiXXX.dylib`, or `gurobiXXX.dll`. You
should update your GUROBI_HOME environment variable to point to the
correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look for the specific `dll` in your hard disk and update the `GARUBI_HOME` accordingly, as per error message? Did you double-check that this specific `dll` exists on that folder?